# Tkinter crashes when clicking a button and remains pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple program with start and exit buttons. The start button makes a notification using win10toast, but the button remains visibly pressed down and the window becomes unresponsive. The exit button works fine before the start button is pressed. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from win10toast import ToastNotifier


root = Tk()


def exit_p():
    exit()

def new():
    hr.show_toast("New", "Alert")
    return


#creates a label widget
myLabel1 = Label(root, text="Full Moon Notification!")
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="Here you can start and exit the program")

button1 = Button(root, text="Start",padx=50,command=new).grid(row=3,column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text="Exit", padx=50,command=exit_p).grid(row=4,column=0)


#puts the widget on the screen
myLabel1.grid(row=0,column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1,column=0)

#loop to keep program running
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `threaded=True` there. I'm not very familiar with either but I guess it's because the event loop is blocked.

Comment: could be that you're not actually calling the method in the `Button` method. Try setting `command=new()`

Comment: @sshah98: no, that is completely wrong.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/47) raised two years ago.  Work around is setting `threaded=True`.

Comment: @user202729 that solved it! '''hr.show_toast("New", "Alert", threaded=True)''' works, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely because `hr.show_toast("New", "Alert")` blocks.

The `win10toast` library conveniently provides an option `threaded=True`, so just change that code to

```
hr.show_toast("New", "Alert", threaded=True)
```

should make it work.